# comment or answer if the solution is little?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

it is possible that only a letter or expression needed to be changes to solve a problem, it can be mentioned in a comment.What should one do in this situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are for clarifying, not for answering.

Comment: yes it is. but sometimes it is enough to make it clear to understand.

Comment: @sgt Just because you *can* answer some questions in a comment doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: this should be a comment :p

Comment: that is what i am asking, why not?

Comment: @sgt - because if you have an answer, you should post it as an answer, not as a comment. Again - comments are for clarifying issues with the post, not for answering it.

Comment: @lostsock - don't think I wasn't tempted to post that as a comment ;)

Comment: ok... got it.. but sometimes it makes me confused what to do.

Comment: @sgt The length of your response is irrelevant. Answers can be short too. If you're answering the question it should be posted as an answer. If you're just asking for clarification of a question it should be posted as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

For some cases, these can be closed as off-topic. If the person just made a spelling mistake or something, then this is the close reason (you can also flag to close):

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely
>   inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem
>   before posting.

In other cases, if only a small change is needed but it's not a spelling error, it would be best to answer the question showing the small change needed and then *explain why*.  A small adjustment to the code is not always obvious and/or trivial.

Comment: This bears repeating: _explain why_